# How does PubNub bind your account with the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

It seems that PubNub binds your account by domain. I can't seem to find a definitive answer in the support nor the API.

By the lack of using publish, subscribe or secret key from JavaScript it seems that your site's domain is what's bound.  Is this accurate?

I haven't gotten around to playing with it, but that would be bad because that would mean that I have push up my code to the server just to test.

I need to know about this because I want a way to test my web application using local host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about PubNub accounts and binding to a domain.  This is a good question regarding how to get started with PubNub.  To dispel this quickly, you **do not have to provide this information with PubNub in order to connect**.  You can connect from **Anywhere** to **Anywhere**.  You can even connect on **localhost** from your local system.  Even better you do not need a web server and can write ordinary html5 and open the **file://** from your hard disk.  Pretty nifty yah?

Mac:

```
file:///Users/stephen/index.html
```

Ubuntu:

```
file:///home/stephen/index.html
```

Windows XP:

```
file:///C:/Documents and Settings/stephen/index.html
```

Windows 7:

```
file:///C:/Users/stephen/index.html
```

Comment: Nice answer, PubNub. I might have to look into this to see what it's all about. :)

Comment: I see now I noticed that you must add the publish and subscribe key to the top of the page